# Functional Programming in java Venkat Subramaniam memoizer

Tags: java, functional-programming, memoization

In the book Functional Programming in java by Venkat Subramaniam, the autor gives us an example of a memoizer that works perfectly, next i leave the implementation of the memoizer class:

```
public class Memoizer {
    public static <T,R> R callMemoizer( final BiFunction< Function<T,R>,T,R> function, final T input ){
        Function<T,R> memoized = new Function<T,R>(){
            HashMap<T,R> store = new HashMap<>();
            @Override
            public R apply(T input) {
                return store.computeIfAbsent(input, key -> function.apply(this, key));
            }
        };
        return memoized.apply(input);
    }
}
```

So here is my question, wouldn't the Function memoized will be created in every call to the method callMemoizer? i assume not because other ways the HashMap store won't be storing all the values...
please someone explain to me how and why that piece of code works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local variable `Function<T,R> memoized = new Function<T,R>()` will be created each time `callMemoizer` is invoked.  The important point however, is that the expensive calculation and association with key will only happen once (assuming your Map is not weak/soft) via `computeIfAbsent`

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Amir, you are right the local variable Function memoized = new Function() will be created each time callMemoizer is invoked, so of course the HashMap store will be created each time callMemoizer is invoked... i guess my doubt arose because i didn't fully understand how the Memoizer was being used, so next i leave the usage of callMemoizer in the example:

```
public static int maxProfit(final int length){
    return Memoizer.callMemoizer( (func,size) ->{
            int profit = (size <= prices.size()) ? prices.get(size-1) : 0;
            for(int i=1; i<size; ++i){
                int priceWhenCut = func.apply(i)+func.apply(size-i);
                if(profit < priceWhenCut) profit = priceWhenCut;
            }
            return profit;
        } 
        , length
    );
}
```

The code actually works because callMemoizer will be called just once and the HashMap will be created just once for evey call, then recursion will use the apply method so all the values will be correctly stored in the hashmap....